# One-particle scattering: LSZ vs Feynman

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, klein-gordon-equation, propagator

This question is about Klein-Gordon theory (the field is hermitian).

If I calculate the amplitude for the process $\phi\to\phi$, I get two different results depending on whether I use Feynman rules or the LSZ formula.

For example, if I use the Feynman rules, I get
$$
p_\text{in} ---\blacktriangleright ---p_\text{out} \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad \mathcal A=\frac{1}{p_\text{in}^2-m^2}=\frac{1}{p_\text{out}^2-m^2}
$$

On the other hand, according to the LSZ reduction formula, the amplitude is (supposedly) given by
$$
\langle f|i\rangle=\int\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\ \mathrm e^{-ip_\text{in}x}\mathrm e^{ip_\text{out}y}\ \Box_x \Box_y \langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle
$$
where $\Box_x=\partial^2_x+m^2$ , and $\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle$ is the propagator. As we know that the Klein-Gordon operator, when acting on the propagator, gives a delta function (i.e. $i\Box_x \langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle=\delta(x-y)$), the amplitude is easly calculated, and equals
$$
\langle f|i\rangle=i(2\pi)^4\delta(p_\text{in}-p_\text{out})(p_\text{in}^2-m^2)
$$
which means that $\mathcal A=p_\text{in}^2-m^2=p_\text{out}^2-m^2$.

Can anybody tell me where is my mistake? I believe that the right result is the first one, so maybe my formula for LSZ is wrong, or cannot be used in a one-particle process?